# How to set the working directory for a <junit> task to something other than the basedir?

Tags: java, ant, junit

I have an Ant script with a junit target where I want it to start up the VM with a different working directory than the basedir. How would I do this?

Here's a pseudo version of my target.

```
<target name="buildWithClassFiles">
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/UnitTest/junit-reports"/>
    <junit fork="true" printsummary="yes">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/UnitTest/bin"/>
            <path refid="classpath.compile.tests.nojars"/>
        </classpath>
        <jvmarg value="-javaagent:${lib}/jmockit/jmockit.jar=coverage=:html"/>
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <test name="GlobalTests" todir="${basedir}/UnitTest/junit-reports" />
    </junit>

</target>
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried:

```
 <junit fork="true" printsummary="yes" dir="workingdir">
```

Comment: You might want to also set forkonce="true" so you don't fork on every test.

Comment: `dir` won't take effect if `fork` is set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answers might be overlooking the fact that you want the working directory to be specified, not just that you want to run junit on a particular directory. In other words, you want to make sure that if a test creates a file with no path information, it is from the base directory you are specifying.

Try to pass in the directory you want as a JVM arg to junit, overriding `user.dir`:

```
 <junit fork="true" ...>
   <jvmarg value="-Duser.dir=${desired.current.dir}"/>
    ....
```

Comment: Actually, my answer above is resetting the directory.  The "dir" argument of the junit task, when used in combination with "fork", will launch the VM in the specified directory.